# HttpListener : writing to outputstream slow depending on content?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, httplistener

Removed the old question & rewriting completely because i've worked on this quite a bit to pinpoint the problem. My issue is that i'm writing a custom CMS with a custom server, with very very high speed/thoroughput as a goal, however i'm noticing that some data or data patterns cause major slowdowns (go from 0 to 55+ms response time). I really need someone better than me helping on this as i'm absolutely clueless about what is going on, i'm suspecting a bug in the .net Framework but i have no idea about where it could be, the little .net code browsing i did didn't suggest the output Stream does anything data-specific

Things that i've tested and am sure aren't the issue:

- Size of the content (larger content is faster)
- Type of the content (difference between the same content types)
- Most of the surrounding code (made a minimalist project to reproduce the bug, standing at around 15 lines, find the link at the bottom of the post, includes data to reproduce it, run it, test with 2 URL, see for yourself).
- Not an issue with webpages / cache etc, issue reproduced with a single image and CTRL+F5 in Firefox, removing the last few bytes of the image fixes it 100% of the time, adding them back causes the issue again
- Not an issue that exists outside of the outputstream (replacing it with a target memorystream doesn't show the issue)

How to reproduce the issue:

- Download & run the project
- Use your favorite browser and go to localhost:8080/magicnumber
- replace magicnumber in that url by what you want, you will receive the image back minus that amount of bytes

My result:

- Constant 50ms or so with that image
- Getting the magic number up to 1000 doesn't affect this at all
- a bit further (i think around 1080 ish?) it suddently drops to 0MS
- Not sure what is going on but it seems there are 2 requests per request at least when using CTRL+F5 in Firefox, in the correct case both are 0ms, in the error case the first remains 0ms but the other becomes 50ms, i'm assuming the first one is simply checking if the file cache is ok & i'm still answering but Firefox closes the connection or something?

Any help is much appreciated, placing all my rep on Bounty there as i really need to know if i go down this path / get more info to report this or if i go lower level and do my own http.sys interop (and, most of all, if the bug is only on the .net side or lower level & going lower level won't fix it!)

The sample file is a gziped array, my content is pre cached and pre compressed in db so this is representative of the data i need to send.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao63d7din939new/StackOverFlowSlowServerBug.zip

Edit : if i have fiddler open, the problematic test gets back to 0ms, i'm not sure what to make of it so far this means i'm getting a major slowdown, when sending some data, which isn't defined by the type of data but the actual data, and this doesn't happen if i have fiddler in between. I'm at loss!

Edit 2 : Tested with another browser just to be sure and, actually it's back to 0ms on IE so i'm assuming it may actually not be a HttpListener bug but instead a Firefox bug, i will edit my question & tags toward that if no one suggests otherwise. If this is the case, anyone know where i should be looking in FF's code to understand the issue? (it definately is an issue even if on their side since once again i'm comparing with 2 files, one larger than the other, same file format, the largest one always takes 0ms the smallest one always 55ms!)

Comment: Are your benchmarks against Windows or Windows Server?

Comment: I did both, the runs i gave are against Windows 8.1, however i don't think there should be a different with a single connection. Note that this isn't a performance problem (which could differ on both based on server vs client settings for connections), but a content-dependant performance issue

Comment: Edit : ran the specific test on a beefy Windows server 2012 DC , it's not conclusive but the times are way lower on it overall, i'll need to find a larger repro case on it but i did see something like that before (was on one of the images that took closer to 200ms on it)

Comment: if you install Fiddler you'll get some info that may help spark the brain.

Comment: I'd be surprised if i did since it's writing to the outputstream that is slow, i'm not sure what fiddler would tell me on top (it's not the download phase that takes 50ms, but the "waiting" phase in firebug). This is not my area of expertise really so if you have any suggestions i'd love it if you could grab the project & run fiddler against it

Comment: No, it's a pre gziped png file. It's also independant of the content type (i don't have this issue with all png files)

Comment: Also not once again the content TYPE is not in cause, it's the content itself (other items of the same content type are working just fine)

Comment: Which version of .net are you using? I just ran your code, and I am finding no indication of your slow down at all.

Comment: 4.5.1 targetting 4.5 through visual studio 2013

Comment: What results are you getting when running it? 0ms for all requests?

Comment: yup 0ms for all tested. Running against a local instance. Also using 4.5.1, but using Windows 8.

Comment: Even if you do localhost:8080/0   ?

Comment: I gave the fiddler test a shot and am about to edit the post to add the results, no clue what to make of it however

Comment: Maybe an idiot question, but any firewall coming in between? We have a firewall at our work which buffers and scans data if content-length is between a specific size range, any distant chance of any such thing?

Comment: Nope, is on loopback (localhost:8080), nothing in between, disabling Windows software firewall doesn't change the result either.

Comment: @Aron, could you tell me if you have the same issue as i do if you test from Firefox? Just edited my post as i'm starting to think this is a Firefox bug.

Comment: Do you have any strange proxies or add-ons configured for Firefox? What are the response times when you look at the developer console in Firefox? (It will only show 1 request)

Comment: I use firebug & that's it for add-ons (i don't even use Firefox except when i do webdev, so the install is really just Firefox + firebug untouched).

Comment: Also in firebug the additional time (vs other browsers) show in green "receiving", if you remove the part that is "receiving" the time are the same as with other browsers, but it can't really be caused by a proxy / firebug since it's dependant on the data & not the type (since even a partial chunk of that data works). It's totally driving me crazy, the more i pinpoint it, the less i understand what could cause this

Comment: Can't reproduce any of your problems of FF, IE, etc. Maybe you could check for extensions, antivirus, firewalls, etc...

Comment: No extentions, no antivirus, default Windows firewall disabled, 100% repro rate for me on FF, never happens on others. Did you try with the project in my post against current FF version?

Answer (score 4):

Two requests problem:

Chrome:

- First request = favicon
- Second request = image

Firefox:

- First request = image for the tab
- Second request = image

More on this:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=341179

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583351

IE:

- Only appears to make the one request

If you send the requests through fiddler you never get two coming through.

Performance problem:

Firstly there's a problem with the timer in your demo app. It's restarted everytime the async request handler fires, meaning that the timer started for request A will be restarted when request B is received, possibly before request A is finished, so you won't be getting the correct values. Create the stopwatch inside the ContinueWith callback instead.

Secondly I can't see anyway that "magicnumber" will really affect performance (unless it causes an exception to be thrown I guess). The only way I can cause performance to degrade is by issuing a lot of concurrent requests and causing the wait lock to be continually hit.

In summary: I don't think there's a problem with the HttpListener class

Comment: You're right didn't think it could be N+1 instead of NX2, however can't mark this as answer, i only put it there in case it was related to the problem but it's not an issue at all (hence why it's in the my result section) to give all of the info but my issue really is "why is some data going very slowly through the outputstream for no apparent reason. Thanks for the hint however, definately helps my curiosity (only happens in the minimalist sample since i'm not checking the urls, not on my server)

Comment: Yeah i get that, I would have added it as a comment however there was too much info. I'm looking at the other part of the problem now

Comment: The demo is really simplistic, as i said it happens "without" any concurrent queries, so there is no query B happening before A finished, i just hit CTRL+F5 & wait untill it's done on a single image, only a few image exhibit this & it's completely unrelated to their size, magicnumber has no reason to affect performance, which is why this is a pretty crazy issue. I don't think there's a problem with HttpListener anymore, everything points to a Firefox bug, i'm (wild guess) thinking that those png have an issue or the reader for them has an issue on the last bytes

Comment: And that instead of downloading then processing Firefox isn't releasing the connection untill it's done processing them, so it "stalls" for 50ms trying to figure them out & keeps the connection open for that time / doesn't finish downloading before. There are no exceptions on the serverside, the requests all complete (and the magicnumber makes it so the image displays fine but partially, only the downloaded part does). Also this is with run of the mill Firefox, no addons at all.

Comment: And it's important to note that performance isn't degrading, it's 100% stable, every single request to all ressources (webpage, png, JPG, css, js) takes 0ms locally except a few images (that are actually smaller than others that take 0ms) which take a flat 50 or so ms (always the same time within 1ms, no concurrent requests). Try one of the wrong files 1000 time, get 50ms 1000 times, try one of the good files, get 0 ms 1000 times. Zero degradation

Comment: In the demo there are concurrent requests because Firefox makes the two requests (the image and then the image for the tab). You can prove this to yourself by adding some "Start" and "End" writelines to the ContinueWith block and putting a Thread.Sleep(100) after Response.Close()

Comment: I can't speculate on how Firefox works but I the connection stalling theory doesn't really make sense to me. Unfortunately I don't have a better one for you.

Comment: The final question is that given this appears to only happen on Firefox, and doesn't really have any impact on your performance, and can't be reproduced by anyone else, what are you hoping to get out of this?

Comment: Aye i understand your point about the concurrent connections, didn't think of this but definately doesn't explain the 50ms (would actually explain lowering the timer not increasing it). I'm not really hoping much out of this except for people to tell me if it actually reproduces on their end when using latest Firefox (as i have a 100% repro rate here), so i guess i'm just hoping to find someone else reproducing it & to try & pinpoint what is the culprit so that i can fill a proper bug report & fill it where it belongs (possibly to Firefox team).

Comment: It also has a very major impact on my performance (means a thread on the server side is stalled for 50ms instead of 0ms, which means when it goes live it will have a huge impact on performance dividing number of concurrent users by 50-100ish). The whole point of making a custom fully cached pre compressed cms was to be extreme high thoroughput (ideally being able to serve 1000s of actual concurrent users on a low end server)

Comment: Since i doubt i'll get more help at this stage of the Bounty & the issue seems really specific i'm going to awarrd the Bounty to you as your answer was helpful for the 2 connection issue, i'll accept my own answer whenever i get to the bottom of this